# Elasticsearch Monitoring Request Failed Unable to find the cluster in the selected time range. UUID:

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have upgraded ELK from 7.8.0 to 7.17.6. After upgrade, not able to set-up stack monitoring with metric beat. Getting below error:

```
Monitoring Request Failed
Unable to find the cluster in the selected time range. UUID: s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw
HTTP 404
```

If i run below command from dev tools:

> POST .monitoring-es-7-*/_search

Output:

```
{
"took" : 29,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
"total" : 7,
"successful" : 7,
"skipped" : 0,
"failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
"total" : {
  "value" : 10000,
  "relation" : "gte"
},
"max_score" : 1.0,
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA:hc-tapolicy-2021-05:0:p",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : {
        "uuid" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "host" : "172.19.0.2",
        "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
        "ip" : "172.19.0.2",
        "name" : "6ff2fb09aa81",
        "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.452Z"
      },
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "STARTED",
        "primary" : true,
        "node" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-tapolicy-2021-05"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:_na:hc-tapolicy-2021-05:0:r",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : null,
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
        "primary" : false,
        "node" : null,
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-tapolicy-2021-05"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA:hc-work-2020.10.19:0:p",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : {
        "uuid" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "host" : "172.19.0.2",
        "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
        "ip" : "172.19.0.2",
        "name" : "6ff2fb09aa81",
        "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.452Z"
      },
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "STARTED",
        "primary" : true,
        "node" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-work-2020.10.19"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:_na:hc-work-2020.10.19:0:r",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : null,
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
        "primary" : false,
        "node" : null,
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-work-2020.10.19"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA:hc-ta_tbl-2020.10.02:0:p",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : {
        "uuid" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "host" : "172.19.0.2",
        "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
        "ip" : "172.19.0.2",
        "name" : "6ff2fb09aa81",
        "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.452Z"
      },
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "STARTED",
        "primary" : true,
        "node" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-ta_tbl-2020.10.02"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:_na:hc-ta_tbl-2020.10.02:0:r",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : null,
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
        "primary" : false,
        "node" : null,
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-ta_tbl-2020.10.02"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA:hc-datamon-2020.10.10:0:p",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : {
        "uuid" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "host" : "172.19.0.2",
        "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
        "ip" : "172.19.0.2",
        "name" : "6ff2fb09aa81",
        "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.452Z"
      },
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "STARTED",
        "primary" : true,
        "node" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-datamon-2020.10.10"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:_na:hc-datamon-2020.10.10:0:r",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : null,
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
        "primary" : false,
        "node" : null,
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-datamon-2020.10.10"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA:hc-tapolicy-2020.10.03:0:p",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : {
        "uuid" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "host" : "172.19.0.2",
        "transport_address" : "172.19.0.2:9300",
        "ip" : "172.19.0.2",
        "name" : "6ff2fb09aa81",
        "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.452Z"
      },
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "STARTED",
        "primary" : true,
        "node" : "i3DVAtpcTEqt5BFtuyXjCA",
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-tapolicy-2020.10.03"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : ".monitoring-es-7-2022.10.18",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w:_na:hc-tapolicy-2020.10.03:0:r",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "cluster_uuid" : "s-J_B794QHeLC_IAPrIaAw",
      "timestamp" : "2022-10-18T00:00:00.453Z",
      "interval_ms" : 10000,
      "type" : "shards",
      "source_node" : null,
      "state_uuid" : "M3nZP-n-TVeOqr4XEHz52w",
      "shard" : {
        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
        "primary" : false,
        "node" : null,
        "relocating_node" : null,
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "hc-tapolicy-2020.10.03"
      }
    }
  }
]   } }
```

I think, the timestamp is not getting updated in the cluster to be identified. Kindly let me know the issue.